# What do you say when you're referring to a chess game?

Tags: american-english, expressions

1. Playing as blacks
2. Playing black
3. Playing with blacks

On the internet, I've found these 3 versions and people are using all of them. However, I don't know which one is a correct version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen plural "blacks" or "whites" referred to in chess.

This is typical, with the colours usually capitalised (in the same way as football team names):

- Fischer playing Sicilian (B99) **as Black**
- Fischer **was Black**
- Fischer **was playing Black**
- **Opening for Black** According to Karpov (book title)
- **Opening repertoire for Black** (book title)
- "What was **Carlsen’s winning Black** move, and why was it decisive?" (Leonard Barden, leading chess writer)
- "**White (to play) is** bishop for two pawns down and threatened with Qxg2 mate, but the schoolboy spotted a tactic which turned the tables." (Barden)

Comment: Good to know. I didn't know this detail. In Chess forums, you'll see people using the plural. Maybe this is because in some other languages when referring to chess the language usually offers plural. Noted!

Comment: @CarlosF - It might help if you edited your question and included an example where you've seen this used on a chess forum. Google just told me: `No results found for +chess "Playing as blacks"`.